# Blum's speedup theorem in big-O format?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

Is there a way to state [Blum's speedup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%27s_speedup_theorem) in terms of [Big-O (Landau) notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation)?

Comment: it seems Blums speedup thm is often stated not in big-O notation as on wikipedia but just noticed that [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlumsSpeed-UpTheorem.html) states the big-O version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blum's speedup theorem implies that for any computable function $f(n,T)$ there is a computable predicate $\Pi$ such that for every program $P_1$ for $\Pi$ there is another program $P_2$ for $\Pi$ whose running time satisfies $f(n,T(P_2)) \leq T(P_1)$. In particular, there exists a computable predicate $\Pi$ such that for every program $P_1$ computing it there is another program $P_2$ computing it and running in time $T(P_2) = o(T(P_1))$.

But the theorem is much stronger: for example, for some other predicate $\Pi$, the guarantee is $T(P_2) = O(\log T(P_1))$; and for another predicate $\Pi$, the guarantee is $T(P_2) = O(T(P_1)/n)$; and so on.